# ViewPager in Fragment with SlidingMenu

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, android-sliding

I wanted to aks how the general approach would be to display a ViewPager inside a Fragment with the help of SlidingMenu:
https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

There are two examples, the frist one is the ResponsiveUI example that has a working menu (it changes the pictures of the birds), however, I don't know how I would change that successfully into displaying different ViewPagers.

The other example is the ViewPager example. It creates a ViewPager to swipe between colors, however, this does not come with a working sliding menu.

Is it even possible to do so?

I have tried to simply replace the content with a ViewPagerFragment

```
mContent = new ViewPagerFragment(); 
    getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content_frame, mContent)
    .commit();
```

but I get following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions
```

Complete logcat here: http://pastebin.com/aD2BSAja

Comment: Were you able to sort out your problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {

    ViewPager mViewPager;
    FragmentPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    protected ListFragment mFrag;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_pager_and_titles);

        // set the Behind View
        setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
        FragmentTransaction t = this.getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        mFrag = new SampleListFragment();
        t.replace(R.id.menu_frame, mFrag);
        t.commit();

        // customize the SlidingMenu
        SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
        sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.actionbar_home_width);
        setSlidingActionBarEnabled(true);

                //ViewPager adapter
        mPagerAdapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        final ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            toggle();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```